# Трудности с изученем обработчика сообщений PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

Да, понимаю, может это и какой-то глупый вопрос, но тем не менее я не могу найти ответа. Проблема заключается в том, что в документации данного модуля есть следующее:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hello'])
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text.encode("utf-8") == SOME_FANCY_EMOJI)
def send_something(message):
    pass
```

Это сложенный обработчик, который создаёт некую "функцию", которая ответит на команду **/hello** или на любой *эмоджи* (вот как раз про второе и будет идти речь).

Именно часть *( ... msg: msg.text.encode("utf-8") == SOME_FANCY_EMOJI)* является мне не понятной.

Начнём по порядку.

- **"msg: "** написанное после функции, определяет "вид сообщения" (?!)
- **"msg.text.encode("utf-8:")"** обозначает кодировку, но зачем её вписывать???
- **... == SOME_FANCY_EMOJI)** самое непонятное для меня: ***"сообщение: кодировка == переменная"***... что?

Решил я, значит, проверить это всё на практике, и получаю ошибку о несуществовании переменной *SOME_FANCY_EMOJI*. Создаю эту переменную, но обработчик не реагирует на эмоджи (по понятным на то причинам пустоты переменной).
Лезу в pypi и ищу там модуль *'emoji'*, и перед обработчиком написал следующее:

```
SOME_FANCY_EMOJI = ':thumbs_up:'
```

Ошибок нет, но не реагирует на эмоцию. Переделываю:

```
SOME_FANCY_EMOJI = :thumbs_up:
```

Ошибка есть. Меняю:

```
SOME_FANCY_EMOJI = ''
```

Ошибки нет, но всё ещё не реагирует, караул!!!!

В этом и состоит вся моя проблема: непонимание строения ***"сообщение: кодировка == переменная"***, и то, что бот не реагирует на эмоции

#### P.S.

Я не смог найти ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: вам стоит пробовать отладить программу. вместо `lambda` используете функцию, и там печатайте, какое значение принимает `msg.text.encode("utf-8")` или `msg.text`, поэкспериментируйте; :thumbs_up: - формат эмодзи для дискорда, и он не будет актуален для телеги. кодировка для обработки символов, которые могут быть неизвестны вам, так просто проще и поведение будет предсказуемее.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за подсказку